# Crashplan on FreeNAS missing /var/lib/crashplan/.ui_info

Tags: nas

So I spent a few weeks on this problem now. I've been trying to get CrashPlan running on a headless FreeNAS server. I have found lots a tutorial to do this. However the fact is that I'm missing the .un_info file on my FreeNAS server after installing CrashPlan.

I have searched the whole file system to try and find the elusive .ui_info file.

I've tried creating it manually with information copied from desktop PC but that does not help me resolve my CrashPlan Pro app connecting to the Crashplan server service on FreeNAS.

INFO:
FreeNAS 9.3 STABLE
Crashplan   3.6.3_1 Plugin

Comment: did you find a resolution?

Comment: Nope, I had to give up I just could not get it to working at all.

Comment: I have the same problem; it seems the CrashPlan plugin is not updating properly. I'm considering blowing away my FreeNAS install and starting fresh.

Answer (score 1):

The crashplan remote access behaviour changed several times during the last updates, however with version 3.6.3_1 you should find the .ui_info file in

```
/var/lib/crashplan/.ui_info
```

Although the jail version is 3.6.3 it's possible that Crashplan updated itself, please check this with:

```
tail -f /usr/pbi/crashplan-amd64/share/crashplan/log/service.log.0
```

In the end you want your Crashplan to update itself anyway. If the update process produces an error related to bash, please run:

```
pkg update
pkg install bash
ln -siv /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

And restart crashplan while checking the log output with the tail -f command from above:
    service crashplan restart

If you finally reach a recent version (>4.4.1), its time to remotely connect to crashplan.

The only change on the server necessary for the easiest method without ssh tunnel is the serviceHost tag in /usr/pbi/crashplan-amd64/share/crashplan/conf/my.service.xml.

```
<serviceUIConfig>
    <serviceHost>0.0.0.0</serviceHost>
```

Either do this everytime you want to connect, because the token will change after every crashplan restart or use my script from here (for OS X): https://gist.github.com/Phlogi/8654e353786ed1cf0858

Copy /var/lib/crashplan/.ui_info to the correct place on your desktop machine and edit the IP address at the end (to your servers address), for example:

```
4339,7f1d655f-*****,192.168.1.20
```

That's it, you can start crashplan on your remote machine and it will connect properly, there are no other changes neccessary. Latest crashplan (>4.4.1) will actually use the IP address from .ui_info.

Comment: Any idea how to get CrashPlan to update itself?  I'm definitely following in @James-Bowen footsteps.

Answer (score 1):

Install JRE. You will need to add `--no-check-certificate` to the JRE wget line in the install.sh file